flutter IOS Build error. Could not obtain access to one or more requested file system resources because CoreDevice was unable to create bookmark data
I'm trying to build an iOS app in debug mode on a real device using Flutter, but I keep getting this error.
message - Could not obtain access to one or more requested file system resources because CoreDevice was unable to create bookmark data.
Domain: com.apple.dt.CoreDeviceError
Code: 1005
my flutter version is up to date.
`[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.19.5, on macOS 14.3.1 23D60 darwin-arm64,
• Flutter version 3.19.5 on channel stable at
• Framework revision 300451adae , 2024-03-27 21:54:07 -0500
• Engine revision e76c956498
• Dart version 3.3.3
• DevTools version 2.31.1
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
• Platform android-34, build-tools 34.0.0
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b829.9-10027231)
• All Android licenses accepted.
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.3)
• Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
• Build 15E204a
• CocoaPods version 1.15.2
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
• Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome
[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.3)
• Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
• Flutter plugin can be installed from:
• Dart plugin can be installed from:
• android-studio-dir = /Applications/Android Studio.app
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b829.9-10027231)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2023.3.6)
• IntelliJ at /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app
• Flutter plugin version 78.4.2
• Dart plugin version 233.15026.12
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2021.3.3)
• IntelliJ at /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app
• Flutter plugin can be installed from:
• Dart plugin can be installed from:
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2021.3.3)
• IntelliJ at /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE 2.app
• Flutter plugin can be installed from:
[✓] VS Code (version 1.65.2)
• VS Code at /Users/n2204001/Downloads/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
• Flutter extension can be installed from:
[✓] Connected device (4 available)
[✓] Network resources
• All expected network resources are available.
`
Is there any way to solve this?
want build ios debug mode app in physical device
